# Execute shell init stuff if called via `ssh user@server myscript`

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

I want to execute shell init stuff before `myscript` is called via `ssh user@server myscript`

I tried:

```
# .bash_profile
echo DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDdddd
```

This works interactively:

```
ssh user@server
DDDDDDDDDDDDDD

user@host>
```

But it does not work like this (DDDDD... is missing)

```
ssh user@server date
Thu 01 Jul 2021 09:01:11 AM CEST
```

How to execute init stuff before `myscript` gets called via `ssh`?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/952084/why-is-ssh-not-invoking-bash-profile

Comment: As suggested already you need to either source the .bash_profile in your script, or put your logic in .bashrc instead.

Comment: You could add it to `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: @Bayou I added `echo PPPPP` to `.profile`. Then I executed `ssh user@server date` and I don't see PPPPP. This means for me, this does not work.

Comment: `date` executes *instead of* the login shell that would have sourced `~/.bash_profile`.  `ssh` doesn't, AFAIK, provide a way to execute arbitrary code prior to the given command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

First it did not work, since I added "echo DDDDDDDDD" at the **end** of my `.bashrc`.

It works if I add it at the **top** of `.bashrc`.

Now my shell lines get executed:

```
ssh user@server date
DDDDDDDDD
Fri 02 Jul 2021 08:40:38 AM CEST
```

These lines in the `.bashrc` (which seem to be default on Ubuntu) are responsible for the confusion:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to source an initialization script before running the `date` command, you can do

```sh
ssh user@server 'bash -c ". /path/to/init.sh; date"'
```

where `/path/to/init.sh` is the path to your desired initialization script.

For example, if you wanted to source `user`'s `.bash_profile`, you can do

```sh
ssh user@server 'bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; date"'
```

If you wanted to execute bash as a login shell on `server` you could do

```sh
ssh user@server 'bash -l -c "date"'
```